# RoR Tutorial Chapter 10. Can't destroy user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't destroy user on the chapter 10 of the tutorial. When I use `rspec` it just lets me pass. But when I tried manually it doesn't give me a javascript confirmation warning. When i hit the delete link it just redirects me to the show user. When I check the logs on the server it said

```
Started GET "/assets/defaults.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-08 21:58:40 -0500
Served asset /defaults.js - 404 Not Found (20ms)
```

I solved it already:

I solved it by changing

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :default %>
```

on app/views/layout/application.html.erb
to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

since no default.js in app/assets folder only, application.js available.

Comment: This error would be caused by you using Rails 3.1, where Rails Tutorial uses 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your link is being rendered like this:

```
link_to "Delete", user_path(user), method: :delete
```

You'll need to ensure that jQuery and jQuery UJS are being required.

This can be done with require calls from your application.js file

```
*= require jquery
*= require jquery_ujs
```

To add a confirm message.

```
link_to "Delete", user_path(user), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have node.js installed? Install and reboot machine if not.

Comment: This should be a commnent!